# How to create lambda with receiver in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know how to create instance of `(String) -> Int` lambda: `{s: String -> s.length }`, but how to create `String.() -> Int` lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the type explicitly to create a lambda with a receiver:

```kotlin
val x: String.() -> Int = { length }
```

More info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver